# Bigdata cluster compatible distributed predictive model

Tags: machine-learning, python

I might be asking a dumb question but my question is can I write a python program (lets say a classifier) using some library that scales in hadoop (not only using a simple parallel processing).The reason I am confused is 
1)The scikit learn python codes don't scale in big data.
2)The spark mlib is written in scala and not in python.
3)Although h2o is open sourced I don't think it is written in python.

Comment: [Using SQL, pandas, and Python for data analysis](http://johnbeieler.org/blog/2013/06/06/using-sql/) & [Reading Files in HDFS with Pandas framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16598043/reading-files-in-hdfs-hadoop-filesystem-directories-into-a-pandas-dataframe) & [Large Data Work with pandas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14262433/large-data-work-flows-using-pandas)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spark does have a pretty good Python API, check out this [tutorial](https://districtdatalabs.silvrback.com/getting-started-with-spark-in-python).

For traditional Hadoop stack, take a look at [mrjob](https://github.com/Yelp/mrjob), it lets you write MapReduce jobs in Python and run them on several platforms.

Answer (score 1):

While checking on python [xgboost](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost) I found the existence of this [open source project](https://github.com/dmlc/rabit) that helps create scalable machine learning program.Should be worth exploring.